# How can I insert multiple data to my database using the Select2 plugin with codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am creating a php system using codeigniter, I want to register several data in a table using a multiple select and the select2 plugin. The problem is that of the data I select, only the last selected data, is the one that is registered in my database. How can I solve it?

**This is the form.**

```js
$('.select2').select2({
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionLength: 20,
    placeholder: "Select maximum 20 items"
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="multiple-basic">
       grupos
   </label>
   <select class="select2 form-control" name="grupos[]"  multiple="multiple" id="multiple-basic">
       <optgroup label="GRUPOS REGISTRADOS">              
        <?php foreach ($group_data as $k => $v): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $v['id_grupo'] ?>"><?php echo  strtoupper($v['nombre_grupo']) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
       </optgroup>
   </select>

</div>
```

### My controller

```html
 <?php
  public function createSingle(){
  $response= array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());  
   $oidVal = implode(",", $this->input->post('grupos'));
      $data = array(
          'id_usuario'=> $this->session->userdata('id_usuario'),
          'id_grupo'=> $oidVal);
      $create = $this->model_users->createSingle($data);
       if($create== true) {
          $response['success'] = true;
          $response['messages'] = 'DATOS REGISTRADOS:';
         }else {
          $response['success'] = false;
          $response['messages'] = 'ERROR AL REGISTRAR LOS DATOS';
         }

          echo json_encode($response);
 }
  ?>
```

### My Model

```html
<?php
 public function createSingle($data='')
 {
  
  if($data) {
   $create = $this->db->insert('registro_grupos_usuarios', $data);
   //$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   return ($create == true) ? true : false;
  }


 }
?>
```

Comment: check what you getting from the post values echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);exit;

Answer (score 0):

select with 'multiple' only returns one value for named input when submitted (or when using `element.value`).

As you're already using jquery you can use `$(element).val()` to get the full list. (Or in vanilla loop through all options with `element.selected` as true)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="dropdown" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
  </select>
</body>


<script>
  document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // eg I have selected 'two' and 'three'
    console.log(event.target.value); // two
    console.log($(event.target).val()); // Array [ "two", "three" ]
  })
</script>

</html>
```